# On Postfix SMTP port change no incoming external mail

Tags: postfix, smtp

When I edit /etc/postfix/master.cf and I replace smtp with submission to enable port 587, I am still able to send emails (SMTP working fine), but can't receive emails from outside (local mails are delivered). I am using dovecot IMAP. When I change SMTP port back to 25 I am able to receive emails again.

Any good idea what could cause the problem?

Tell me if you need any configuration files.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

Basically, port 25 is what other email servers will try to speak to your server on.

If you aren't listening on port 25, then external servers will not try any other ports. 
So in order to have the outside world speak to you, you need to be listening on port 25.

Outgoing email still works basically for the same reason: your server knows to try and contact other servers on port 25, and those other servers are listening.

The setup it sounds like you want is as follows:

- allowing incoming external email on port 25 (which in general just means leaving your config alone)
- using the submission port for your users to send email

Generally, the reason for doing things this way is that you would typically want your users to authenticate before they can send email, whereas you don't expect external servers to.

Another way of saying the same thing is that for your domain, you only want legitimate users to send email, and you authenticate them to ensure that. For domains other than your own, you don't have this concern, and will accept mails from external servers (whether or not you validate their 'right' to speak for a given domain is another matter).

The first case is what port 587/submission is for, the second case is what port 25/SMTP is for.

So you have one set of rules/processing (defined in master.cf) for server-to-server communication (on port 25), and one set of rules/processing for user-to-server communication (on port 587, aka submission port).

You might want to read the 4-part series that appeared on Ars a while back:

- [part 1](https://arstechnica.com/information-technology/2014/02/how-to-run-your-own-e-mail-server-with-your-own-domain-part-1/)
- [part 2](https://arstechnica.com/information-technology/2014/03/taking-e-mail-back-part-2-arming-your-server-with-postfix-dovecot/)
- [part 3](https://arstechnica.com/business/2014/03/taking-e-mail-back-part-3-fortifying-your-box-against-spammers/)
- [part 4](https://arstechnica.com/information-technology/2014/04/taking-e-mail-back-part-4-the-finale-with-webmail-everything-after/)